# como eliminar un elemento de un array vue js

Tags: javascript, array, vue.js

tengo un array de la siguiente manera.

```
[ "icono-5-4", "icono-7-6", "icono-8-7", "icono-9-8", "icono-1-0", "icono-2-1" ]
```

Quiero eliminar reactivamente un elemento: 
Sabre el nombre del elemento hasta que el usuario le de click a un botón. Ejemplo, si el cliente le da click un boton y el boton tiene el valor   **icono-9-8**

tendria que borrar ese elemento de mi array

```
[ "icono-5-4", "icono-7-6", "icono-8-7", "icono-1-0", "icono-2-1" ]
```

y asi sucesivamente para esto yo utilizo:

```
_.pull(this.array, 'icono-9-8');
```

pero esto no estan reactivo o no lo hace tan rapido como quiero.

```
this.array.slice(id, 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé muy bien que estás haciendo, no entiendo lo de `_.pull(this.array, 'icono-9-8');`.

Puedes usar `splice()` para eliminar un item mejor que `slice()` ya que vue observa los cambios con `splice()` y modifica el *array* en lugar de crear uno nuevo.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    lista: ["icono-5-4", "icono-7-6", "icono-8-7", "icono-9-8", "icono-1-0", "icono-2-1"]
  },
  methods: {
    del: function() {
      var indice = this.lista.indexOf('icono-9-8');
      if (indice != -1)
        this.lista.splice(indice, 1);
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in lista">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button @click="del">
  borrar
  </button>

</div>
```

Comment: Esto funciono el _.pull(array, elemento_a_borrar); es un método de lodash que te permite eliminar elementos de un array. Pero al igual que lo hace slice no estan reactivo como splice

Answer (score 0):

Hola que tal si intentas con array filter:

```js
let arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

let value = "b"

arr = arr.filter(function(item) {
  return item !== value
})

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: esto lo sigue dejando reactivo?